# Resample/Increase the resolution of Digital Elevation Model by QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I have a DEM of 5m pixel. I wonder is it okay to convert it to 2m pixel? How to do that using QGIS?

And what would happen to the original data, I mean the accuracy? Would it be reliable?

Comment: What do you mean by "is it okay"? Nobody is going to arrest you for doing it. What do you mean by "reliable"? All data is unreliable in some sense. Have you looked at the QGIS raster processing options for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You just right click the layer and choose `Export > Save As` to do that in QGIS 3.x, define the extend as current layer extend and define resolution.

[image]

No problem resampling the image. **But** you can't increase the accuracy by increasing the resolution. Because the spatial resolution of the **source DEM** is 5m after all. In that case you just increase the number of pixels in the same area.

Comment: Then what would happen to the image after resampling in in terms of pixel value and resolution? I tried on an image and noticed that the value for the same point did change.

Comment: Value may change because of interpolation used. But the accuracy doesn't increase. *But the opposite is true. If you convert DEM 2m to DEM 5m, the accuracy decreases.*

Comment: Think of a picture with 1000x1000 pixels. Changing the size into 2000x2000 doesn't increase the quality of the picture.