# Changing spatial resolution of raster layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, resolution

I'm working with the Hansen forest loss year data from Global forest watch (which is 30m per pixel) as part of my MSc thesis to look at deforestation risk of palm oil. All I want to do is to change the spatial resolution of this layer to 100m or to match the palm oil data - current help guides have confused me as they each suggest something different and I've no idea what 'cell size' I need to get a spatial resolution of 100m. I'm using QGIS 3.2 Odense.

Comment: So you have a raster with a pixel size of 30 m and don't know how to `transform` (hint!) it to 100 m pixel size?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/317971/162856

Comment: I was told that Pixel size and spatial res were different? I've tried Warp and Align raster neither of which are working

Comment: Welcome to SEGIS!  Could you please describe your two data sets ("Hansen" and "palm oil") in more detail, including their source, and their projected CRS values?  Also, do you need the two resulting 100m pixel-sized rasters to perfectly align, so that their cell boundaries overlap exactly in x-, y-, and rotational space, or would you accept some displacement?  Screenshots sure would help!