# Changing 10m to 20 m Resolution in QGIS

Tags: raster, resolution, multi-resolution-raster

I have Esa world data of 2020 it is in 10m resolution and I want to change it to 20m resolution in qgis. How can I do it ?

Comment: One method is described in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317961/resample-increase-the-resolution-of-digital-elevation-model-by-qgis/317971#317971

Answer (score 5):

There are at least 3 ways to change the resolution of a raster image with QGIS.

- Use Layer-Export-Save as.. and give the resolution

[image]

- Use Raster projections-Warp from the processing toolbox with an extra parameter `-tr`. It does not change the projection if you do not set the Target CRS

[image]

- Use Raster-Translate from the processing toolbox and use the same `-tr` parameter as with warping.

Read more about the supported parameters from https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html and https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html. You may want to change for example the resampling method from the default.